# Elementary work in magnetic matter

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, energy, magnetic-fields, work

In section 5.16 Jackson$^1$ derives energy density in magnetic. With that in mind, he derives the expression of elementary work to build the configuration
$$\delta W=\int\delta\boldsymbol{A}\cdot\boldsymbol{J}\thinspace d^3x\tag{5.144}$$
or in terms of the fields
$$\delta W=\int\boldsymbol{H}\cdot\delta\boldsymbol{B}\thinspace d^3x\tag{5.147}$$
After that, Jackson states this is the analogous to the electrostatic formula in a dielectric, that was derived in section 4.7
$$\delta W=\int\boldsymbol{E}\cdot\delta\boldsymbol{D}\thinspace d^3x\tag{4.86}$$
that in turn comes from the work to add some free charge $\delta\rho$ to the configuration
$$\delta W=\int\delta\rho\cdot\Phi\thinspace d^3x\tag{4.84}$$
First of all, I don't understand why in the magnetic case $\boldsymbol{B}$ is varied instead of $\boldsymbol{H}$, like in the electrostatic case where $\boldsymbol{D}$ is varied. Why don't we vary the auxiliary field in both situations?
Or rather, comparing $(4.84)$ to $(5.144)$, why don't we vary the free currents, as we do for free charges in the dielectric case, and instead vector potential is varied?
I'm asking for physical intuition why this is so.

---

$^1$<sub>Jackson, Classical Electrodynamics 3rd edition. The equations above are enumerated according to this edition.</sub>

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand and describe it.
The descriptions from (equation 30.1) to (euation 30.2) in Sec. 30 "Thermodynamic relations in a magnetic field" of (Landau and Lifshitz's book; Electrodynamics of continuous media)   may be helpful.

Comment: It seems that at the beginning of the section you mentioned (that is actually Section 31 in my edition) , L&L addresses my question saying "*Their derivation, however, is quite different from that given in §10*. This difference is ultimately due to the fact that a magnetic field, unlike an electric field, does no work on charges
moving in it [...] Hence, we must examine the electric fields induced by the change in the magnetic field and determine the work done by these fields on the currents which produce the magnetic field. "

I'll wait for further confirmation, though.